# Bad practice to have same letter in immediate succession in domain?

Tags: dns, usability

Generally speaking, when considering a domain name is it bad practice to have the same letter in immediate succession (twice) forming the overall  domain name? An end user typing in this domain may for example become confused and omit one of the letters that appears twice.

In which case if using a domain with the same letter in immediate succession due to works that begin/end in the same letter. Would it not be an idea to purchase two domains? One for the full domain name and one that redirects if the letter that should have been typed in has been omitted:

For example when considering the domain name baddog:

www.baddog.co.uk

www.badog.co.uk (for end users who omit one of the d's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your potential user becomes confused when writing "baddog", how do you expect him to write "www." and ".co.uk"?

Anyway, average user doesn't write urls nowadays. Make sure you're first position in search engines when searching for your name or for approximations of your name.